# Passing form data to another form Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode, forms, ipad, storyboard

Ok first off I am uber new at Obj C programming and even more new at using Xcode. Right now I am creating a app that a customer info controller. From the customer info controller, there is a button that goes to billing info. This both of these controllers have a form that needs to be filled out, BUT on the billing one I have a button that can be clicked to bring data from the customer info page if it is the same info. Now for the life of me I am not able to find anything that can assist me in making this happen. How it is setup is one textfield to the next...I.E...on the customer info page, First name is filled out and then on the billing page if it is the same one it will correspond to it as well and so forth. Any help or direction to get me to this would be great. Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method [prepareForSegue:sender:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/prepareForSegue%3asender%3a) is perfect for that.

Comment: Well atm i dont have code... Everything i have done is through the Storyboard. I have send and read the prepareForSegue:sender but it doesnt really explain how to set each text field to its corresponding text field

Comment: I know that, this is what i am trying to figure out, and needing some help or point me in a direction to go